# Scrolling page add extra padding on top on logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Scrolling down the page add extra padding above the logo. I need to figure out a way to align the logo properly with rest of the site.
Here's what I have tried out so far:
I have commented out this line in line in my js file.

```
//$('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" });
```

Here's the link to my [site](http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/)
Please note: This issue is replicated only on scrolling the page up or down.

Comment: That padding is from two of your CSS files on .navbar-brand class. "style.css" and "bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: So, you want to remove the padding top on the logo which appears after scroll? Best way (imho) is to alter the plugin you are probably using. A quicker way is to use !important on the padding-top: 0px statement. You can do this in your regular css file.

Comment: Please provide the code to the whole nav. the menu itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scrollback to top of the page. There are added  `padding-bottom: 27px; padding-top: 27px;` in `navbar-brand` anchor tag.

Remove it when scroll to top back. It will solve your issue.

[image]

It is added from some JavaScript Or Jquery.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have now added `.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
 color:#777
 padding-top: 0!important;
}` but its still the same

Comment: Adding !important here won't do anything since the styling you're talking about is **inline**. Try to add a function when you scroll back to the top and remove this styling by doing `$('.navbar-brand').removeAttr('style');`